# OpenCV Empty Binary Image C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm looking to create a binary image in OpenCV where all the values are initialised to 0. I want it to have dimensions 2000x800.

So far I have:

```
Mat canvas(2000, 800, 1)
```

But I want it so that the values of each pixel can only be a zero or a one.

Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenCV does not support bitfields i.e. Mat's of depth 1 bit. There is sound reasoning in this; operating on bitfields is markedly slower because a bit is not an intrinsic operating type for the hardware. Getpixel and setpixel would therefore need extra operations.

```
Mat canvas = Mat::zeros(800,600,CV_8UC1);
```

Will create a zero-initialized image of depth 8 bits; 7 bits will be wasted.

Answer (score 1):

From [its documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat), you can declare:

```
Mat canvas(2000, 800, 1, Scalar(0));
```

to initiate and fill the canvas with 0.