# How to create binary, NOT grayscale image in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

Is it possible to create binary, not grayscale image?

(So it would use 8 times less memory)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/1586352/3132173

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a binary image, but it won't save space.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28768453/3345375).